# Imprimir resultado de una función de una BD

Tags: php, mysql, funciones

El problema es en como puedo imprimir el resultado que me arroja una función que esta en una base, me retorna un varchar, y ese valor lo quiero mostrar.
Hice un print_r y me sale esto:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [baja_empleado(1)] => No se ha eliminado. ) ) 1
```

Yo solo quiero que me muestre lo de "No se ha eliminado."

Mi función es esta:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE FUNCTION `baja_empleado`(id INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE cve INT;
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(50);
    SET cve=(SELECT COUNT(id_em) FROM empleado WHERE id_em=id);
    IF (cve>0) THEN
        SET msg="No se ha eliminado.";
    ELSE
        DELETE FROM empleado WHERE id_em=id;
        SET msg="Se elimino correctamente.";
    END IF;
    RETURN msg;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: como lo estas ejecutando?

Comment: Si el valor  `id` es tomado por ejemplo de un formulario en PHP/HTML, lo más fácil sería ejecutar esta consulta desde PHP: `SELECT COUNT(id_em) cve FROM empleado WHERE id_em=?` y en el mismo PHP hacer la verificación que haces en tu procedure. `$cve=$cve-del-select; if ($cve>0) { echo "No se ha eliminado";  }else{ echo "Se eliminó correctamente"; }` Para pasar la consulta desde PHP se recomienda usar PDO o MySQLi y usar en este caso consultas preparadas.

Comment: Hacer una consulta `SELECT` para verificar si existe un empleado es innecesario, un mejor acercamiento sería ejecutar la consulta `DELETE` y comprobar si hubo o no filas afectadas utilizando [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php). Así como esta ahora, estás buscando en la tabla dos veces el mismo registro.

Comment: `rowCount` no es precisamente el mejor método en PDO para verificar si hay datos  o si una consulta tuvo éxito @MatiasOlivera. Basta con verificar los mismos datos. Puedes ver [este interesante artículo](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count) al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

Como tienes un objeto que se encuentra dentro de un arreglo indexado, primero tenemos que acceder al primer elemento del arreglo mediante su índice: `$array[i]`

```
$respuesta[0];
```

y luego, acceder a la propiedad de la clase con la notación  `$objeto->clave`.

```
$respuesta[0]->baja_empleado;
```